# What does Share do?

Tags: performance-tuning, core-language

One of my recent evaluations ran out of memory. I have discovered the `Share` command. It seems to be a free lunch. Why not turn it on by default? Following is a segment from the document:

> Using Share will never affect the results you get from the Wolfram
>   Language. It may, however, reduce the amount of memory used, and in
>   many cases also the amount of time taken.

Comment: maybe you can refer share in theano in python.link http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/compile/shared.html

Comment: I haven't been using it much myself, but I think that since it doesn't always really help and always results in a bit of overhead when called, it makes sense to leave invoking it to the user. I suggest that you read the [memory management tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/MemoryManagement.html) to learn more.

Comment: Are you asking what Share[] does behind the scenes?  I think that's quite clear from the documentation. It scans for duplicate expressions and merges their storage.  (This may take a long time.) Can you explain what else you want to know?

Comment: There is no such thing as a free lunch. You will pay for using `Share` in time performance. There is always a tradeoff between time performance and memory performance.

Comment: @m_goldberg However, according to the documents, `in many cases also` reduces `the amount of time taken`. It is implies that this command can reduce memory for sure and reduce time in `many cases`?

Comment: @Szabolcs You are suggesting because it may take a long time in some cases, so it is not turn on by default? However, if `in many cases` it do reduce the time and memory, why not turn it default on and for special cases turn it off?

Comment: This is not something you turn on or off.  It is something you *run* once. When you run it, it takes a long time.  Sharing *is* being used all the time when appropriate.  In `a = {1,2,3}; b= {a,a}`, the list `{1,2,3}` is stored only once because you inserted it into `b` through the same reference (`a`).  But in `({1,2,3},{1,2,3})` it isn't because it was explicitly typed out twice. In that case you can run `Share` to detect that something appears twice, and it will share their storage. However, it has to scan everything in memory to do that and that's slow.

Comment: @Szabolcs In this case this option will almost always be slow. Why the documents say that in many cases this operation also reduces the amount of time taken?

Comment: Running Share is slow.  Once you have run it, certain things may be a little faster.

Comment: @Szabolcs This means the document is misleading? They should say something like `in some special cases, Share may also reduce the running time`.

Comment: It seems pretty accurate to me ... "It may, however, reduce the amount of memory used, and in many cases also the amount of time taken."  It means that after running `Share`, memory usage may decrease and some operations may run faster.  But it is not guaranteed that this will happen.  It depends on the specific situation. It also says nothing about how long `Share` takes to run, but from experience, it can be a quite noticeable time.